# Prove that if the cone is cut along a generator and flattened into a plane, then the geodesic becomes a straight line.

Tags: polar-coordinates, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

The is a problem from *Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes* by George F. Simmons. The chapter is about the calculus of variation.

The hint is to represent equation of a right circular cone  $z^2 = a^2(x^2+y^2)$ where $z \geq0$ parametrically by using

$$x=\frac{rcos(\theta\sqrt{1+a^2})}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$$
$$y=\frac{rsin(\theta\sqrt{1+a^2})}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$$
$$z=\frac{ar}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$$

Show that parameters $r$ and $\theta$ represent ordinary polar coordinates
on the flattened cone. And then show that a geodesic $r = r(\theta)$ is a straight line
in these polar coordinates.

I don't know that to get the equation for right circular cone into polar coordinates. Just plugging those for $x,y$ and $z$ into equation of a right circular cone won't do the trick.
I just get

$$\frac{a^2r^2}{1+a^2} = \frac{a^2r^2}{1+a^2}$$

Also showing that we get polar coordinates on the flattened cone is a problem.

I guess that to show that geodesic is a straight line, I have to solve Euler-Lagrange equation. But this is the last step of a problem and I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What type of curve follows a surface such that the line is straight when the surface is flattened](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726242/what-type-of-curve-follows-a-surface-such-that-the-line-is-straight-when-the-sur)

Comment: I was looking at this answer, but I don't understand the parametrization $(r,\theta)↦(r,\theta,ar)$. Why is $z = ar$. Also why is radius scaled by $\sqrt{1+a^2}$ and angle by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$

Comment: I have added a parenthesis to explain more the cylindrical parametrization$z=ar\,.$ About scaling with $\sqrt{1+a^2}\,:$ Imho it is trivial: $d\rho^2=(1+a^2)\,dr^2$ and $\rho^2\,d\phi^2=r^2\,d\theta^2\,.$

Comment: I needed a lot of time to digest it, but I think now I got everything.