# Calculating surface of a solid bounded by cone and plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I need to find the surface area of a solid bounded by $x^2 = z^2 + (y-3)^2$ and $2x+y=12$.
Once I set up the integral I can calculate it,but the problem is that I don't know how to set it up.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/3d can help to visualise the objects.

Comment: The given cone is infinite. Do you have another constraint? Or is the solid the part of the cone between its vertex and the plane?

Comment: I have only these 2 constraints

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for a link :) I didn't know it exists.

Comment: @user170231 The two constraints are sufficient. When the angle between the plane and the cone axis is bigger than the angle between the axis and the _generatrix_ (and the plane does not contain the apex), then there is a bounded solid region between the two surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The first transformation I would make is to replace $y-3$ with $y$ which turns the equations into
$$
x^2=z^2+y^2\,,\quad 2x+y=9\,.
$$
Then let's rename the variables to have compatibility with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726242/what-type-of-curve-follows-a-surface-such-that-the-line-is-straight-when-the-sur/4727780#4727780):
$$
z^2=x^2+y^2\,,\quad 2z+y=9\,.
$$
I believe that with the methods in that linked answer
one can unfold the $\color{red}{\text{cone}}$ into the $\mathbb R^2$-plane and get an equation for
the $\color{blue}{\text{ellipse}}$ that is the intersection of the cone and the plane $2z+y=9\,.$

By isometry of the metric $ds^2$ on the cone with the
metric in $\mathbb R^2$ this should lead to the following formula for the surface area in OP:
$$
A=\int_0^{\sqrt{2}\,\pi}\int_0^{\color{blue}{\rho(\varphi)}}u\,du\,d\varphi
$$
where
$$
\rho(\varphi)=\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{2+\sin(\varphi/\sqrt{2})}\,.
$$
The area $A$ is the one inside the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ contour
in the second picture below.

[image]

[image]